# Showing a function is not differentiable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to show that $$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^2+1}{(x^2+y^2)} \ne 0
$$

I have tried computing the limit along the path $y = mx$, however part of the limit has a division by zero, i.e.

$$\lim_{(x, mx) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2-x}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} + \frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$

With a polar coordinate conversion I get

$$\lim_{(r) \rightarrow (0)} r \cos^3\theta \space -\sin^2\theta \space + 1 
$$

which I don't know how to bound

Comment: It is immediate since numerator tends to $1$ and denominator vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

It is immediate to see that the limit is not zero since numerator tends to $1$ and denominator vanishes.

Indeed, let consider for example $x=t^2$ and $y=t^3$ with $t\to 0$ then

$$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3-y^2+1}{(x^2+y^2)}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac1{t^4+t^6} $$

Comment: I was under the assumption we cannot compute the limit if the denominator is zero

Comment: @Okeh You acn derive the result exactly as for the limit of one variable. The change by the variable $t$ can help. Note we haven't shown what the limit is but we can exclude that it is zero.